# Weird error with xymatrix and pmatrix.

Tags: errors, matrices

Please look at the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\(
\xymatrix{
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}
}
\)
\end{document}
```

The output I get is the following:

```
[PDFLaTeX] test.tex => test.pdf (pdflatex)
[PDFLaTeX] finished with exit status 1
./test.tex:0:No file test.aux.
./test.tex:7:Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. }
./test.tex:7:Missing \endgroup inserted. }
./test.tex:7:Missing } inserted. }
./test.tex:7:\begin{document} ended by \end{pmatrix}. }
./test.tex:7:Missing } inserted. }
./test.tex:7:Missing $ inserted. }
./test.tex:7:Missing } inserted. }
./test.tex:7:Missing } inserted. }
./test.tex:7:Missing } inserted. }
./test.tex:7:Missing } inserted. }
./test.tex:7:Missing \cr inserted. }
./test.tex:7:Misplaced \cr. }
./test.tex:7:Missing \cr inserted. }
./test.tex:7:Misplaced \cr. }
./test.tex:7:Missing \cr inserted. }
./test.tex:7:Misplaced \cr. }
./test.tex:7:Missing \cr inserted. }
./test.tex:7:Misplaced \cr. }
./test.tex:7:Missing \cr inserted. }
```

It goes on like that "for ever". What's the problem here? Does xymatrix not work well with pmatrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\xymatrix{ {\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}} }

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Rasmus: Don't forget that you can "accept" the answer if it worked for you -- click the checkbox on the left of this answer right below its score. This will notify the others that this solution worked for you.

Comment: @Martin: I'd usually wait with such comments (see our Building Blocks), but probably you've seen that.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks, I am aware of that (as becomes apparent when looking at my profile). I do not think that it is advisable to accept the first answer right after posting the question. This answer helped me very much, though, and I will soon accept it unless someone comes across who explaines me even *why* the extra parentheses are necessary.

Comment: @Rasmus: The alignment character `&` has a meaning both to `\xymatrix` and to `pmatrix`. By grouping the complete inner matrix in braces, you ensure that `pmatrix` evaluates it before `\xymatrix` does.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the [xyguide](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy-3.8.5/doc/xyguide.pdf) explain that entries should not start with a macro.

But here, the real problem is the "&" who is interpreted by xypic like a separator in the xymatrix (and not in the pmatrix).

For exemple, `\xymatrix{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \end{pmatrix} }` works fine.